# SQL in VBA erro: Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference

Tags: sql, excel, vba, group-by

Trying to extract data with this query and group by Item number, but getting error:

> Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not
> an outer reference

When try to use Order by getting error that need to use GROUP BY.

```vb
' Database source and connect
dbstr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & get_market_setting(market, "Data Source") & _
        ";Initial Catalog=" & get_market_setting(market, "Initial Catalog") & _
        ";Integrated Security=SSPI"

sourceDb.Connect (dbstr)

' Date from/to filter
date_from = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("H3").Value
date_to = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("H5").Value

' Set Header filter
table_TSE = "[" & get_market_setting(market, "Database") & "$Trans_Sales Entry]"

' SQL query string
myquery = "SELECT  " & ItemNo & ", -SUM( " & NetAmount & " ) FROM " & table_TSE & _
    " WHERE " & ItemNo & " IN " & Itemnr1 & _
    " AND [Date] BETWEEN '" & date_from & "' AND '" & date_to & _
    " GROUP BY '" & ItemNo & " '"

MsgBox myquery

' Set Recordset to query set database on SQL string
Set sourceRs = sourceDb.OpenRecordset(myquery)

'Assign Data to variable from RecordSet'
sourceRs.MoveFirst
   
sourceRs.Close
sourceDb.CloseRecordset
```

Comment: Can you also show us the final SQL query.

Comment: Added more code in post

Comment: You don't need quotes around the GROUP BY column and you are missing a quote around your `date_to` variable.

Comment: Your concatenated query has a few missing parentheses and quotes, even needless quotes like the `GROUP BY` column. Also, where is the `ORDER BY` attempt? What does the `MsgBox` output? Try `Debug.Print myquery` and post result from immediate window (CTRL + G)

Comment: SELECT  [Item No_], -SUM( [Net Amount] )   FROM [Sales Entry] WHERE [Item No_] IN ('80465458' , '30323763' , '453058' , '20336407' , '60505587' , '70343938' , '90488930' , '90465453' , '459480' , '60465464' , '20459479' , '50343939' , '40504659' , '319178' , '50090116' , '30409498' , '50137581' , '40404886' , '30484261' , '10472061' , '90110061' , '504816' , '70495700' , '40484171' , '20396745' , '70444956' , '40484166' , '40064702' , '80452106' , '70484155' , '50466869' , '20262878' , '90409872') AND [Date] BETWEEN '2021-11-02' AND '2021-11-29' GROUP BY '[Item No_] '

Comment: This is how it looks in immediate window

Comment: Found the problem, it was quotes near group by, thanks for the help